# thinking-sphinx pagination query 0 error: offset out of bounds, max_matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have TS 3.0.6, will_paginate 3.0.5 and sphinx 2.0.4

I paginate results in my search by using page option:

```
@products = Product.search(query_string, {
  order: ordering,
  ranker: :bm25,
  sql: { include: :images },
  with: {
    price_type_for_search => min_price_conditions..max_price_conditions,
    kind_cd: @params[:kind_cd],
    brand_id: [*@params[:brand_ids]],
    category_ids: categories_for_search,
    property_value_names: [*params[:property_value_names]].map{ |s| Zlib.crc32(s) },
  },
  page: @params[:page],
  per_page: @params[:per]
})
```

I get error like

```
query 0 error: offset out of bounds (offset=12, max_matches=12); query 1 error: offset out of bounds (offset=12, max_matches=12); query 2 error: offset out of bounds (offset=12, max_matches=12); query 3 error: offset out of bounds (offset=12, max_matches=12)
```

where 12 is the @params[:per] value.

Else I use `will_paginate @products` in my view, but I think that doesn't matter. Why I get an error? How can I avoid it?

I send these parameters to the search:

```
order: :created_at
ranker: :bm25,
sql: { include: :images },
with: {
  # no matter
},
page: 2,
per_page: 12
```

If I send per_page == 18 & page == 2, then I get `query 0 error: offset out of bounds (offset=18, max_matches=18) et.c.` If I send per_page == 12 & page == 3, I get `(offset=36, max_matches=36)` in my error.

Comment: What are the request parameters being sent through when you receive this error?

Comment: @pat please see the edits

Comment: You're not setting max_matches anywhere at all?

Comment: No, grep don't give me anything

Comment: I'm not sure what the cause of this problem is. I can't spot anything in the Thinking Sphinx code that suggests it's the cause. Does it work without using the will_paginate helper?

Comment: It work w/o will_paginate. This is TS error. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: What version of will_paginate are you using? And are you calling the helper before listing each search result? Or after?

Comment: wp 3.0.5 sorry. It don't work successful without will_paginate. It was my error.

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug this further without access to the app

Comment: @pat, can I give you access to bitbucket repo?

Comment: Sure, I just created an account, my username is patallan.

Comment: Thanks, Pat! I invited you to `zhivojoffice/zhivoy-office` repo.
The actual code in 'app/services/query/products.rb' and in 'products#index'

Comment: You can do `rake db:migrate`&& `rake db:sample` to fill the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I've figured it out. The issue here is that the `facets` method was called upon `@products` in the above example. Facet calls don't like the `:page` and `:per_page` options, as facet calls only have *one* page. Hence, viewing page two or more of the search results would throw an error.

A workaround (which I tested locally) is to put most of those search options in a shared method:

```
def common_search_options
  {
    order: ordering,
    ranker: :bm25,
    with: {
      price_type_for_search => min_price_conditions..max_price_conditions,
      kind_cd: @params[:kind_cd],
      brand_id: [*@params[:brand_ids]],
      category_ids: categories_for_search,
      property_value_ids: [*params[:property_value_ids]],
    }
  }
end
```

And then create separate objects for the search results and the facet results:

```
@products = Product.search(query_string, common_search_options.merge({
  sql: { include: :images },
  page: @params[:page],
  per_page: @params[:per]
}))

@product_facets = Product.facets(query_string, common_search_options)
```

And of course, you'll want to change any references of @products.facets to @product_facets. This will ensure that facet searches don't have the pagination options, and everything should now work smoothly.

Comment: Thanks, Pat, I understood the idea! How can I award you?

Comment: Looks like you marked my post as the answer, so that's awarded. If you meant reward, none is needed :)

Comment: Also, you should now remove me from your bitbucket account too.

Comment: Pat, I confused with these two words :) Removed you from bitbucket. And again, thanks!